# How to plot a legend according to a given scale, separately?

Tags: plotting, legending

Suppose I have plot a `ListDensityPlot` graph, the value of the density is between `xmin` and `xmax`, and the change of the plot color is given by `Log[x/xmin]/Log[x/xmax]`. Now I want to create a corresponding legend, how to achieve this?

Let `xmin=0.3`, `xmax=15`, **the scaling of the color should vary according to the log scale, not linear**, the effect should more or less look like this:

[image]

Comment: A concrete example might be useful here.  Is the issue primarily the scaling in the legends or simply the desire for two legends, each of which you can figure out the details yourself?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I mean the scaling.

Comment: I don't see a V10-specific issue here. The question is valid in all versions, and all answers so far work in versions 9 & up (that I can test).  The [tag:version-10] does not seem justified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you meant, but

```
xmin = 0.3; xmax = 15;
f[x_] := Log[x/xmin]/Log[x/xmax]
minmax = {f[xmin], f[xmax - 10^-10]};
cf = Blend[{Red, Green}, Rescale[f[#], minmax]] &;
```

then

```
BarLegend[{cf, {0.3, 15}}, ScalingFunctions -> {Log, Exp}]
```

[image]

Comment: I have no `ScalingFunctions`, my version is 10.

Comment: @buzhidao This works in V10 & V9 for me.  The automatic tick marks in V9 are a bit awkward, but `BarLegend[{"SunsetColors", {0.3, 15}}, Ticks -> {0.3, 1, 3, 10, 15}, ScalingFunctions -> {Log, Exp},  LegendLayout -> "Row"]` fixes that; and works in all versions V9-11.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks, it works with your modifications.

Comment: how was this answer accepted? The function `f` literally returns negative values for all `x`, so the `BarLegend` comes out all solid red, and even with a fixed `f` the ticks won't correspond to the correct colors returned by `cf` at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can also generate the contours yourself (second argument to `BarLegend`). Here's a way to make a function that preserves the syntax of `BarLegend` but uses sort-of log scale:

```
$scalingFactor = E/2;
$scalingRange =
  Rescale[
   ($scalingFactor^Range[1, 10, .1]),
   $scalingFactor^{1, 10}
   ];
barLeg[{cf_, {xmin_, xmax_}}, ops___] :=

 BarLegend[{(cf@Rescale[#, {xmin, xmax}] &), {xmin - .01, xmax + .01}},
  Round[Rescale[$scalingRange, {0, 1}, {xmin, xmax}], .01],
  ops
  ]
```

And since we have enough contours it uses a continuous gradient. Here's your gradient:

```
barLeg[{
  Blend[
    Thread[{
      Rescale[{.3, 1, 3, 10, 15}, {.3, 15}],
      {Hue[.5, .5, .5], Hue[.6, 1, .5], Hue[0, 1, .8], Yellow, White}
      }], #] &,
  {.3, 15}},
 LegendLayout -> "Row"
 ]
```

[image: sample gradient]